# jQuery hover after visit subpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem with some jQuery code.

When I load my home page the slideDown on hover function on picture is working, but when I visit other subpages and then return to my home page the function slideDown on hover isn't working.

EDIT:
You can see that on my page: [193.218.134.131:3000](http://193.218.134.131:3000)

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.standard').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').show();
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').hide();
        }
    );
    $('.fade').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(250);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(250);
        }
    );
    $('.slide').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideDown('fast');
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideUp('fast');
        }
    );
});
```

```
<div class="grid-block slide">
    <div class="caption">
        <h2><%= link_to "About us", about_path %></h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <p><%= link_to "About us", about_path, :class => 'learn-more' %></p>
    </div>
    <%= link_to image_tag("about2.jpg", :class => 'img-rounded img-responsive', :alt => 'test alt'), about_path %>
  </div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Why is this not working properly?

Comment: You need to throw some more details as to what you meant by _jQuery isn't working_!!!

Comment: You read all my message?
I have written that:

When I load first time my home page the slideDown function on picture is working, but when I visit subpages and return to my home page, function slideDown on hover isn't working.

Comment: I am navigating to other subpages. You know. I have about.html, prices.html... And form index.html I am going to about.html and return to index.html

Comment: @mgmaciekmg, clever clogs ha! :) My comment was on your original post and not on the edits you've made. And, to your problem, you do not navigate away from the page! All you have is overlays.

Comment: @LShetty, yup but I have write similar text before I edit my post :) You are right, I have not describe at all my problem.

Comment: @humble.rumble Sorry I have so slowly internet... :( I was cloning repo from git... Try now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here we go. You actually do not navigate away from the current page at all. All you do is load overlays, manipulate the `DOM` accordingly. This is when your events get messed up. The solution you're after is [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

> From the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/): Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

Here is a demo as to how you can modify your code to keep events intact on dynamic `DOM`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on({
        'mouseenter': function() {
            $(this).find('.caption').slideDown('fast');
        },
        'mouseleave': function() {
            $(this).find('.caption').slideUp('fast');
        }
    }, '.slide');
});
```

Change the other 2 sections of your code to match up the above pattern. Hope that helps.

Comment: you are my hero :) It's working. I need to learn more about JS... Thank you very much :)